# Hadoop producing no output?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've recently started learning how to use the Hadoop system, and decided it's time to try writing some code. Before that, I wanted to try running the examples seen in the [Getting Started page](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Execution). However, it does not seem to produce any visible results.

I'm currently using Hadoop version 3.3.1 using a single-node setup,
and using jdk 11.0.11. I am running this on Windows 10 (due to current development requirements).

I've used the following command on cmd:

```
hadoop jar %hadoop_home%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.1.jar grep input /output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

The output to the command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>hadoop jar %hadoop_home%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.1.jar grep input /output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
2021-12-15 00:33:10,486 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2021-12-15 00:33:10,800 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/E/.staging/job_1639519343908_0005
2021-12-15 00:33:11,029 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 10
2021-12-15 00:33:11,108 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:10
2021-12-15 00:33:11,281 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1639519343908_0005
2021-12-15 00:33:11,281 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2021-12-15 00:33:11,442 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2021-12-15 00:33:11,443 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2021-12-15 00:33:11,497 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1639519343908_0005
2021-12-15 00:33:11,527 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://DESKTOP-S15C716:8088/proxy/application_1639519343908_0005/
2021-12-15 00:33:11,528 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1639519343908_0005
2021-12-15 00:33:19,611 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1639519343908_0005 running in uber mode : false
2021-12-15 00:33:19,615 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2021-12-15 00:33:31,178 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
2021-12-15 00:33:32,263 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 60% reduce 0%
2021-12-15 00:33:39,624 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 90% reduce 0%
2021-12-15 00:33:40,632 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2021-12-15 00:33:41,636 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
2021-12-15 00:33:41,648 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1639519343908_0005 completed successfully
2021-12-15 00:33:41,760 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 51
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=6
                FILE: Number of bytes written=3021766
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=31877
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=86
                HDFS: Number of read operations=35
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
                HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
        Job Counters
                Killed map tasks=1
                Launched map tasks=10
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Data-local map tasks=10
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=89653
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=8222
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=89653
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=8222
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=89653
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=8222
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=91804672
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=8419328
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=819
                Map output records=0
                Map output bytes=0
                Map output materialized bytes=60
                Input split bytes=1139
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=0
                Reduce shuffle bytes=60
                Reduce input records=0
                Reduce output records=0
                Spilled Records=0
                Shuffled Maps =10
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=10
                GC time elapsed (ms)=90
                CPU time spent (ms)=0
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=2952790016
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=30738
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=86
2021-12-15 00:33:41,790 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2021-12-15 00:33:41,814 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/E/.staging/job_1639519343908_0006
2021-12-15 00:33:41,855 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2021-12-15 00:33:41,913 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2021-12-15 00:33:41,950 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1639519343908_0006
2021-12-15 00:33:41,950 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2021-12-15 00:33:42,179 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1639519343908_0006
2021-12-15 00:33:42,190 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://DESKTOP-S15C716:8088/proxy/application_1639519343908_0006/
2021-12-15 00:33:42,191 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1639519343908_0006
2021-12-15 00:33:55,301 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1639519343908_0006 running in uber mode : false
2021-12-15 00:33:55,302 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2021-12-15 00:34:00,336 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2021-12-15 00:34:06,366 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
2021-12-15 00:34:07,375 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1639519343908_0006 completed successfully
2021-12-15 00:34:07,404 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 50
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=6
                FILE: Number of bytes written=548197
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=212
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
                HDFS: Number of read operations=9
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
                HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=1
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Data-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=3232
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=3610
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=3232
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=3610
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=3232
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=3610
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=3309568
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=3696640
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=0
                Map output records=0
                Map output bytes=0
                Map output materialized bytes=6
                Input split bytes=126
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=0
                Reduce shuffle bytes=6
                Reduce input records=0
                Reduce output records=0
                Spilled Records=0
                Shuffled Maps =1
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=1
                GC time elapsed (ms)=13
                CPU time spent (ms)=0
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=536870912
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=86
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=0
```

Yet when viewing the contents of the now-made 'output' folder,
I receive the following result:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /output
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 E supergroup          0 2021-12-15 00:34 /output/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 E supergroup          0 2021-12-15 00:34 /output/part-r-00000
```

I.e. there's no data written to those files!
May anyone please assist me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no data in your HDFS `input` folder that matches the `grep` pattern `'dfs[a-z.]+'`, then the output will be empty

From the linked docs (which are for Unix, not Windows), make sure this command completed

```
bin/hdfs dfs -put %HADOOP_HOME%/etc/hadoop/*.xml input
```

And you can `grep dfs $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/*.xml` (at least on Unix) as well, locally, to verify there **should** be data output

Comment: I have already filled the input folder with the appropriate files from %HADOOP_HOME%/etc/hadoop/, which is why this is so very confusing.. So trying to run the command you gave outputs a 'file exists' on every file in the folder.

Comment: Okay, so the mapper works `Total input files to process : 10` and `Map input records=819`. Which means some argument is filtering out the data. For example, try using some exact string like `dfs` rather than with a regex pattern. Or run a different example from that jar